# Linking broken edges in images using python

Tags: python, image-processing, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am working on a project to predict contours using unet.

I got the end result as follows: [image]

It has got lot of broken edges especially in case of cluttered objects. I tried to dilate the image, but the result is like this, [image] The edges got thickened which is not a desired behaviour for my application.

Is there any other way by which I can close the edges and improve the results?

Comment: Do you have a version of that image before binarization? The raw probably output might be a better start point.

Comment: It is not binarized image, it is the output of unet trained for boundary prediction.